# My Samsung device is rooted but Magisk is "not installed"

Tags: samsung, rooting, android-10, magisk

I have a `Samsung A7 2018` `(SM-A750F)` `Android 10` `A750FXXU5CVJ2`, today I rooted my phone through patching the AP file in `Magisk v25.2` installed on my stock firmware, then I flashed the patched AP using ODIN along with the original BL, CP, CSC files from my stock firmware. It's worth noting that on my stock firmware (before flashing), Magisk showed that `ramdisk` is available, but after flashing the patched firmware, Magisk showed that `ramdisk` is not available on the patched firmware. Now I have root access, I checked through Root Checker app, but Magisk says that it's not installed.

**Note**: I have seen a lot of threads about this problem online, some said to flash a patched custom firmware (I want the original one), and some suggested to flash the `Magisk.apk.zip` file, but I don't want to do that since It's advised by the creator of Magisk not to do so [Custom Recovery](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#custom-recovery), and TWRP is not supported on my device. Another suggestion is to uninstall the current Magisk Manager and reinstall it, I have done that but to no avail.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: try another Magisk [1](https://github.com/topjohnwu/magisk-files/commits/master/stable.json), [2](https://github.com/topjohnwu/magisk_files/commits/master/stable.json)

Comment: @alecxs Do I just change channel to custom and paste URL of stable.json of the version I want to downgrade to?

Comment: @alecxs I updated the channel and tried to install an older version (v24.3) but it doesn't install (I tried v22.0 as well). It only installs v25.2. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it also didn't work. I think I have to reroot my phone using an older version.

Comment: @alecxs When I uninstall and reinstall Magisk 22.0, it installs but it doesn't open, the app opens and closes immediately and then it prompts me to download and install v25.2. I think it has to do with the patch, it refuses all versions but v25.2.